# order list by using sum of its fields

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am developing a MVC application and I want a list of items order by descending by using the sum of its field's valued. I got the sum but its not getting ordered by descending based on that sum.

```
var SharedStories = (from p in PublishedLivestories select p).ToList();

SharedStories = (from p in SharedStories
                 let totlaSharedCountOfStory = SharedStories.Sum(s => s.SharedOnFacebookCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnGoogleCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnInstagramCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnLinkedInCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnPinterestCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnTwitterCount)
                 orderby totlaSharedCountOfStory descending
                 select p).ToList();
```

`totlaSharedCountOfStory` is my sum of fields and I want list in descending order by `totlaSharedCountOfStory` . Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result= SharedStories.OrderByDescending(x => x.SharedOnFacebookCount 
                                               + x.SharedOnGoogleCount 
                                               + x.SharedOnTwitterCount 
                                               + x.SharedOnInstagramCount 
                                               + x.SharedOnLinkedInCount 
                                               + x.SharedOnPinterestCount)
                                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use order by after selecting SUM() as ::

```
SharedStories = (from p in PublishedLivestories.ToList()
                    select new{
                    totlaSharedCountOfStory = p.Sum(s => s.SharedOnFacebookCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnGoogleCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnInstagramCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnLinkedInCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnPinterestCount
                                                                   + s.SharedOnTwitterCount)
                   }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.totlaSharedCountOfStory).ToList();
```

Comment: `p` is a single item here and I can not apply `p.Sum` to it